# FastAPI can't access global queue?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm creating a local app. I'd like to be able to shutdown the server from am api call, but do not have any success.

Here're some code:

```py
# q.py
from multiprocessing import Queue
q = Queue()
def stop_server(*args, **kwargs):
    q.put("EXTERMINATE")

# app.py
app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/kill")
def index(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(stop_server)
    return {"killed": True}

# main.py
from q import q

def start_server():
    uvicorn.run(app="app:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8080)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = Process(target=start_server)
    server.start()

    # sleep(5)
    # q.put("EXTERMINATE")
    # sleep(3)
    while True:
        msg = q.get()
        if msg == "EXTERMINATE":
            while server.is_alive():
                server.terminate()
                sleep(0.1)
            server.join(timeout=1)
            q.close()
            break
```

Accessing "127.0.0.1:8080/kill" does nothing.

There is a commented block that manually put a message into the queue. If you uncomment the code, you should see the server terminated successfully.

So, how could I access the queue from inside a fastapi handler?

Comment: I think the problem is that you may be creating two instances, or more, of the Queue(). For example, when you hit the endpoint "/kill" you are calling stop_server, which use an instance of Queue(). Later in the main.py file, when you import the variable q, this is another Queue() instance, in  which the "EXTERMINATE" wasn't put. If this is the case, maybe you should define the queue in the main file, and pass it as argument to Process class or something like that.

Comment: @Gealber Thanks! I figured it out! Passing the queue with app factory did the job.